# On iOS. When an app gets sent to the background, Is the app still running on the same UI thread or does it get moved to a new different thread

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin, background-thread

On iOS. When an app gets sent to the background, Is the app still running on the same UI thread or does it get moved to a new thread?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS allocated thread pool for your app is not altered, upon entering a background state (of course they are suspended though).

You can review which thread you are currently on by examining `NSThread.Current`.

#### Examples:

- If you look at the thread in `DidEnterBackground`, yes it is the `main` thread.
- A background fetch (`PerformFetch`) will be on the `main` thread.
- Background-based Location updates are on the `main` thread.

i.e.

```
switch (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState)
{
    case UIApplicationState.Background:
        Console.WriteLine($"Background location update {NSThread.Current}");
        break;
    case UIApplicationState.Active:
        Console.WriteLine($"Foreground location update {NSThread.Current}");
        break;
}

Location[16904:1947553] Foreground location update <NSThread: 0x60000006d900>{number = 1, name = main}
Location[16904:1947553] Foreground location update <NSThread: 0x60000006d900>{number = 1, name = main}
Location[16904:1947553] Foreground location update <NSThread: 0x60000006d900>{number = 1, name = main}
Location[16904:1947553] App entering background state.
Location[16904:1947553] Now receiving location updates in the background
Location[16904:1947553] Background location update <NSThread: 0x60000006d900>{number = 1, name = main}
Location[16904:1947553] Background location update <NSThread: 0x60000006d900>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Comment: So my app sequences through a queue of downloads asynchronously on the UI thread. if the app is processing downloads and it goes into background, I know any downloads that have already been passed to the iOS download task will continue to download, but will downloads I still  have queued on my UI thread still be processed and sent to the iOS download task?

Comment: @StackMan Once you enter a background state (`DidEnterBackground`) you have about 20/30 seconds to wrap things up. You can request a background task via  `BeginBackgroundTask` that will give you 5 to 10 minutes of app background processing before being suspended. Xamarin has a good guide that provides an overview of this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/